# Questions about sums of reciprocals of certain sets of natural numbers

Tags: number-theory

> Let $\mathbb{N}$ be the set of natural numbers and for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let  $F_{n} = \{F \subseteq \mathbb{N}: \#F = n\}$ and $G_{n} = \{G \subseteq \mathbb{N} \cap [n, \infty): \#G = n\}$.
>
> (a) Show that $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \{\sum_{\ell \in G} \frac{1}{\ell} : G \in G_{n}\} \subseteq \mathbb{Q} \cap (0, 1]$.
>
> (b) Show that $\mathbb{Q} \cap (0, 1] \subset \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \{\sum_{\ell \in F} \frac{1}{\ell} : F \in F_{n}\}$.

I think the $F_{n}$ are $$F_{1} = \{1\}, \quad F_{2} = \{1,2\}, \quad F_{3} = \{1, 2, 3\}, \quad \ldots$$

The $G_{n}$ I do not understand.

Comment: The use of `\mathit` was unnecessary. You can make braces within MathJax by using `\{` and `\}` or `\lbrace` and `\rbrace`. Other commands I will point out: `\mathbb` for blackboard bold (like $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$), `\subset` and `\subseteq` for $\subset$ and $\subseteq$, and `\#` for $\#$. [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for how to typeset common math expressions with LaTeX, and [see here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to use Markdown formatting.

Comment: Please give your questions descriptive, informative titles (so that people can understand what the question is about *from the title*) and keep the question self-contained in the post - that is, don't start writing in the title and then just keep going in the body, rather the body should contain the entire text of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $F_n$ are the set of all $n$ element subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ so for instance $F_1=\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\ldots\}$, as for the $G_n$ it would probably be clearer to write $G_n=\{F \,|\, F\in F_n \text{ and } \forall m\in F, m\geq n\}$ so a $G\in G_n$ if it has $n$ elements and they are all at least $n$.

So for a you just want to show that for each $n$ and each $G\in G_n$, the sum of the reciprocals of $g\in G$ is less than 1 (clearly it is rational and positive).

To do this notice that each element of $G$ is at least $n$ and there are $n$ element so
$$
\sum_{i\in G} \frac{1}{i}\leq \sum{j=1}^n\frac{1}{n}\leq 1$$
Which shows the containment.

For b I am unclear if you need to show strict containment or not, I will show both. Strictness is easy {1,2} for instance for instance is not in RHS.

For containment let $\frac{a}{b}\in\mathbb{Q}\cap(0,1]$, with $a,b$ coprime. We need to find an $n$ and $F\in F_n$ so that the sum of reciprocals is $a/b$ but as these $F$ are arbitrary subsets it suffices to show that we can find a finite collection of distinct natural numbers so that the sum of the reciprocals is $a/b$. I imagine that you would first take the largest $n$ so that $\frac{1}{n}\leq \frac{a}{b}$, if you have equality stop, if not then find the largest $m$ so that $\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{m}\leq \frac{a}{b}$ if you have equality stop, otherwise keep going. You have to show that this terminates in finitely many steps, but I have to go eat dinner now.

Comment: James: Your description of $G_n$ is off: Its members are the elements of $F_n$ whose least element is $n$ or larger. (So $G_n\subset F_n$.)

Comment: So it is, thanks for the spot.